# Chrome snippet pauses while browser is minized or that particular tab is not being viewed

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

I have a js code running in the snippet of chrome but it pauses everytime the browser is minimized or that particular tab where the code needs to run is not viewed. How can I fix this?

Comment: That depends on what the snippet does. So far it sounds like you're doing something that depends on the page and the page has its own script that pauses updates when the tab becomes invisible - many sites are doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the script is specific to the webpage. Is there any way to determine if it's a website's script that is stopping it for sure? Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Run `getEventListeners(document)` (also with `window`) and see if there are `blur`, `pagehide`, `visibilitychange` events. Then you can remove the listener e.g. document.removeEventListener('blur', getEventListeners(document).blur[0])